# Calculating visual intersection of the cross-section of an object with a circle in screen-space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, glsl

So, this is a somewhat tall order, since I've never heard of anyone doing this in a game and every option I've seen requires that I learn a new language. Here's the context:

First-Person Shooter games such as Team Fortress or Overwatch model any weapon with a "cone of fire" or inaccuracy as a spray of a large number of hitscan lines. This means that the damage you do to any given target comes out to approximately the intersected area of the cross-section of your cone of fire and the cross-section of the target, divided by the total area of the cone of fire's cross-section, multiplied by the sum of the damage your weapon can deal at that range if all shots hit.

In other words: 
[image]
 where the box is the target, and the circle is the cross-section of the cone of fire, and the red overlap is the fraction of the circle to multiply by the total possible damage of the gun.

The only way to do this that I would know how to do is a raycast for every pixel in the circle, which is a non-starter due to how expensive and un-scalable that would be. Is there any way to get the object a pixel is rendering as it renders? Is there a way to do booleans of objects in screen space? I've seen shaders that do stuff like this, can I take the information those shaders are using and use that?

The reason I'm doing this in screen space specifically is to avoid the unintended hits from intersecting players that happen when you use a world-space raycast from the center of the player where the object hit is behind or clipping through the camera.

Comment: I see possible variants: 1. Classify all possible intersections of circle with rectangle and  calculate are of intersection sectors/segments geometrically 2. Approximate circle by n-gon (perhaps n~12 is enough) and calculate intersection of two convex polygons (result is convex polygon too)

Comment: you got depth in screen space, you got your circle position and orientation (I guess center of view axis aligned to view direction) so just simple shader pass would do this easily just pick any fragment around largest circle possible (based on visibility and cone angle) and then inspect those fragments and compute their angle to your aim.... so something like: `dot((0,0,-1),(x,y,z-z0))<cos(0.5*cone_angle)`  where `z0` is the cone start point `z` coordinate (gun) assuming you are viewing in `-Z` direction.